# How to sum identical rows in a k-dimensional array?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

How do I sum the identical rows  in a k-dimensional array?
e.g If I have an array `X[k,i,j]`where `X={}, 1<=k<=K, 1<=i,j<=N`
I want to sum all the values in the first row `X[k,0,j], 1<=k<=K, 1<=j<=N` and similar to the remaining rows but I can't write `for` loop for it.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried? Also is this `numpy`?

Comment: I am using `ortools` but I haven't tried `numpy`